# Detect HTML and CSS for a DIV and change to make it scroll with a sibling DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Chrome extension and one of the features it does is generate a full page length screenshot by snapping a screenshot image of the viewport then scrolling down the page and repeating the process until it has an image of the whole page length and stitches them together as 1 image using HTML5 Canvas.

Page elements that are `position: fixed` get changed to `position: absolute` so that it doesn't show the fixed element in each viewport image in the final image repeated over and over!

Now I have a page for example that gives a new challenge. 
https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/linux#ubuntu-15.10-wily-werewolf

**Based on the image below...**
**1)** the top header bar is `fixed` so it changes to `position: absolute`
**2)** the main page right scrollbar scrolls the main right content panel down the page.
**3)** the left sidebar has a separate scrollbar for it's DIV.

When my extension makes a screenshot on this page, it ends up repeating the left sidebar contents over and over all the way down the page since the right scrollbar goes much furthor down the page.

I think the solution is to somehow detect and make the left sidebar in these cases be positioned so that it does not have a scrollbar and instead will show all the left sidebar content as the right content DIV is scrolled down.

I am just not sure about how to do that left sidebar part at the moment, any suggestions?  I would need to detect this situation on other pages automatically as well!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CSS overflow is what you are looking for, I guess. 
Try setting overflow: visible to that sidebar. Now the "auto" value is likely to stand there.

What about detecting... You can check the scrollHeight of the element and get its height, for instance sidebar.scrollHeight > sidebar.offsetHeight. If it's true, it means it is scrollable.